# Copy text from current document to new window.open("otherdomainURL")

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I would like to take a given text from a document and copy it to a pop-up window (window.open) that contains a form generated by a server-side back end (rails in this case) this form is loaded from a different domain that the present document, containing the text to be copied. This text would be displayed in the form (reviewed by the user) and then be submitted to the server, through a POST form action.

I initially wanted to use document.write() but this will not be possible since the pop-up page will be loaded from a different domain.

Query strings in this case will not help due to the limits on chars. Any other options?

Answer (score 1):

Most modern day browsers support [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) where you can pass information to the new window.

If you are working with older browsers, your best bet is to post a form to that domain's page with the content and that server will read the posted data and fill out the form.

Comment: Thank you. The lack of support for IE 8/9 is unfortunately a deal breaker, so I will have to do two posts to the domain. Would you recommend plain js or JQuery for this?

Answer (score 0):

You best bet will probably be to have a script in the popup window call for the text from the other screen. Rather than try and pass it to the popup window.

Use an ajax call to the main page and get the text for the text field and update the text field when you get it.

Comment: Hell no! ajax call to the parent?! why?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use zero-clipboard-rails. See [zero-clipboard-rails on github](http://github.com/nragaz/zero-clipboard-rails).

Answer (score -1):

If you can edit the page that is loaded in the new window then here s something you can do using JavaScript. Before opening the new window, set the copied text to a variable in the parent window.

```
var copiedText = 'text to be copied';  //e.g. $('#some-textarea').val()
```

Then load the new page. Inside the new page add a call to the 'opener' window's variable using

```
opener.copiedText
```

and use it to populate the form element.

Comment: The pop up is in a different domain, you can not read the opener!

Comment: It does not matter if he can edit both pages, you can not read from Domain A to Domain B because of the same origin policy.

Comment: i stand corrected (though there could be a workaround to that as one does not get the same origin policy warning while using Google Maps API!)

Comment: JavaScript map uses JavaScript from their domain and use JSONP to communicate with their server.